# How to create instances of other classes using a templated class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I am experimenting with templates, and was wondering if it's possible to achieve something like this:

```
template<typename T> class TemplatedClass{

private:
    T n;
    T z;
    T x;


public:

    TemplatedClass(T n, T z, T x) {
        this->n= n;
        this->z= z;
        this->x= x;
    }
```

Where this template class would create instances of itself using its constructor based on given data, something like:

```
struct Mystruct{
    string n;
    int x;
    float d;

};


void TemplatedClass<T>::createInstances(T o){
   TemplatedClass<Mystruct> tc(o.getS(), sizeof(o), 16.2f);
}
//Where (T o) is any other class that contains some function that returns a string.
```

Is this even possible? from my research I found that it could be with C++11 using Variadic templates 
but wasn't exactly sure how to implement it.

I am trying to create instances of that templated class based on whatever the data members in the struct would be, in this case, its string, int, and a float, and we're getting the data from other classes as long as they match the struct.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `TemplatedClass<Mystruct>` has three members of type `Mystruct`, and its constructor takes three parameters of type `Mystruct`. Not a `string`, `int` and `float`. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It is very very very unclear indeed

Comment: I am trying to create instances of that templated class based on whatever the data members in the struct would be, in this case, its string, int, and a float, and we're getting the data from other classes as long as they match the struct.

Comment: Well they must all have the type MyStruct don't they ? Are you trying to give the parameters and instantiate three different copies for n, x and z with the same parameters ?

Comment: What's the point? What would you use `TemplatedClass<Mystruct>` for, that you can't just use `Mystruct` directly? Instead of describing your proposed solution, describe the original problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The idea was that by having a template class, we create a function template that takes any type of class (as long as it has some function that returns a string), then create Objects based on the data from the struct, in the future, the struct may change, and we might use a char instead of ints, etc. Thus, the template class needs to have generic data members that could accommodate for this change.

Comment: Why do those "Objects" have to be of type `TemplatedClass<Mystruct>` and not simply `Mystruct`? What is `TemplatedClass<Mystruct>` supposed to have that plain `Mystruct` lacks? Why can't `createInstances` do `Mystruct tc(o.getS(), sizeof(o), 16.2f);` ? Imagine that, somehow, you've implemented the class the way you want. Show an example of how you plan to use this facility. As things stand, your question appears to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Like I said in the beginning of the question, this is for experimenting with templates. There are probably 100 other (and better) ways of achieving this, but I wanted to know if its possible with a template class that has a constructor and multiple data members that can be changed at any time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly (and I'm not sure I do), then you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> class TemplatedClass
{
private:
    T1 n;
    T2 z;
    T3 x;
};

struct Mystruct
{
    std::string n;
    int x;
    float d;
};

int main ()
{
    auto tc = TemplatedClass <decltype (std::declval <Mystruct> ().n),
                              decltype (std::declval <Mystruct> ().x),
                              decltype (std::declval <Mystruct> ().d)> {};
    std::cout << typeid (tc).name ();
}
```

Output:

```
14TemplatedClassINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEifE
```

But the number of data members in the templated class has to be fixed.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PD1Yz9p85kWs5tPW)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would this be possible with a constructor in that Template class instead?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Perhaps you could add an example of what you're trying to do to your question.  But there's no reason why the templated class should not have a constructor, if that's what you mean.